# Password Protected Excel Download using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, epplus

I am exporting data in Excel form using **EPPLUS** Excel Library. I want that when excel downloaded it will ask for password. I have tried following code.

```cs
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("sample.xlsx");
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile)
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("demo");
    ws.Cells[A1].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, false);
    package.Workbook.Protection.SetPassword("EPPLUS");
    package.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just need to use the `.Save` overload with a password as the option:

```
package.Save("password");
```

**Response To Comments**

To apply a password if saving via a `byte` array it is very similar:

```
Byte[] bin = pck.GetAsByteArray("password");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullFilePath, bin);
```

Comment: Thanks Ernie!! I have similar problem when write excel using template, My code is ' Byte[] bin = pck.GetAsByteArray();
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullFilePath, bin);' so how can i add password?

Comment: It's working .but when I open excel from mail then it shows me a warning for the recover  file.

Comment: @rinkuChoudhary WIthout more info it is difficult to say.   Post a new question with your code and hopefully people can help.

Answer (score 6):

It's not documented, but you can do as following:

```
package.Encryption.Password = "your password here";
```

Then serve your package with `Save()` or `GetAsByteArray()` of your choice

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the excel package into a MemoryStream (for sending as an email attachment) you have to do this:

```
excelPackage.SaveAs(memoryStream, "pa$$w0rd");
```

Answer (score 0):

package.GetAsByteArray("sometest"); ---> this will protect your excel sheet with password sometest :)